# What file types can be played in Android MediaPlayer class?

Tags: android, media-player, file-type

I've made some RTFM [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), but I am still not sure what files can be played with MediaPlayer. .wav can be, I know. How about .mp3, .ogg, .flac? I don't need video files now, but it can be useful to know about them too. Link to the list of file types will be just enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for this documentation link: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

Its given on developers website http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html